# iOS: Update class method every x seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm completely self taught in iOS programming and Objective-C, so excuse my lack of knowledge when it comes to overall lingo.

I have an `ACViewController` class with its respective .h and .m files.

Also, I have files named `ACPortrait_Orient.h` and `ACPortrait_Orient.m`, and my `ACPortrait_Orient.m` contains the class method `+(void)updateTimeLabel:(ACViewController *)mainView` with the code to make my label show the current time (it is declared in `ACPortrait_Orient.h` also).

In my `ACViewController.m` I have `[ACPortrait_Orient updateTimeLabel:self];` with `#import ACPortrait_Orient.h` included.

I have tried running `[self performSelector:@selector(updateTimeLabel:) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];` inside of my `+(void)updateTimeLabel:(ACViewController *)mainView` method, however I get the following:

> 2014-02-20 01:04:09.212 AlarmClock[5013:70b] +[ACPortrait_Orient setTimeLabelPortrait:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100073e98
>   2014-02-20 01:04:11.218 AlarmClock[5013:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[ACPortrait_Orient setTimeLabelPortrait:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100073e98'

I want the time label to update every second, but this way of going about it just doesn't seem to be working. Is there anyway for me to run that class method every second?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling like this

`[self performSelector:@selector(updateTimeLabel:) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];`

Call like this

```
[ACPortrait_Orient performSelector:@selector(updateTimeLabel:) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
```

Comment: He is in a class method, when sending `perfromSelector:…`. Therefore `self` points to a class object.

Comment: Yes it's a class method so you should call it with class name instead of instances

Answer (score 0):

First of all to have the correct terms: This is not a (compile-time) warning, but a (run-time) exception.

Second, the run-time does not throw the exception, because it did not find `+updateTimeLabel:`. This works pretty well. It misses `+setTimeLabel:`. I bet, that you have an instance method `-setTimeLable:` only.

There are two ways out:

- Implement `+setTimeLabel:`.
- But it seems to be better to use a shared instance (or a regular instance) with instance method instead of class methods.

But to give you a good advice we need more information. Why did you use class methods? (Please do not add this in a comment, but in the Q.)

Answer (score 0):

try this logic to update time every second. If that is only the application

```
@implementation ViewController
UILabel *label ;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 200, 20)];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateTimer{
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    label.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said your code is calling `+[ACPortrait_Orient setTimeLabel:]`, but the exception said you are calling `+[ACPortrait_Orient setTimeLabelPortrait:]`, check where you really called `+[ACPortrait_Orient setTimeLabelPortrait:]`, does this method even exit?